# iMessages Compression for message history

Tags: iphone, messages

Is there some way to compress messages for iMessage? My friend and I talk a lot and at the moment between all of the attachments and messages my iMessages is taking 2.5G of space on my phone.

What can I do to compress this data or back it up or something?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're jailbroken, yes, otherwise, not really.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way is to extract your messages and back it up manually.

**For example :**
https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/tutorials/how-to-transfer-and-backup-sms-and-imessages

After that, you can zip it :)